# Site Manager - "webpage cannot be found" when moving or copying a site

Tags: site-contents, copy-content

I am getting the dreaded "The webpage cannot be found" message when attempting to either move or copy a site from one site to another.  I've confirmed the action did not execute.

I've searched the internet, but haven't found much on the topic.

Comment: perhaps the site relies on other dependencies from its previous parent site, e.g. master page, etc. you can try to apply the default master page, maybe it helps

Comment: how are you doing this operation? is this site move within the Site Collection or outside, if outside, same web app or a different one? what customization you have on the current site? Can you be sure you have ll the site level features matched at the target? are you doing any DB migration? which version of SharePoint are you using? Please give more information in you questions, as the information you provided is not helpful in finding a solution.

Comment: what is the SharePoint version

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information in my post.  I am relatively new with SP.  I am self taught for the most part.
This is SharePoint 2013.  I am running the Site Manager from the SP server.  Right now I have the parent and a bunch of subsites.  I want to have 3 child sites under and divide the other sites as grandchildren to the parent under the three child sites.  I am not doing a DB migration.